# why i am getting 66.24000000000001 when substract 100 - 33.76 in js

Tags: javascript

why I am getting 66.24000000000001 when substract 100 - 33.76 in JS

[image]

trying to substract 100 - 33.76 and getting 66.24000000000001
`// Write, Edit and Run your JavaScript code using JS Online Compiler let b = 100 - 33.76 console.log(b);`

when i run it i am getting 66.24000000000001.
the right answer is 66.24, i calculate this also and getting 66.24.

Comment: I encourage you to read this https://dev-tips.com/javascript/why-0-1-plus-0-2-results-in-0-30000000000000004-in-javascript . Also to prevent this you can use toFixed(x)